# CCAvenue- error after redirect to the payment gateway error code 112

Tags: payment-gateway

I am working with wordpress and integrated the ccavenue payment gateway while redirecting to payment option i am getting an error code 112 afer redirect to the payment gateway...whats the error code indicates

Comment: Maybe you should say how you integrated it and what plugins are activated.

Answer (score 2):

I get 112 when I come from a URL which is not registered with ccAvenue. They will only except posts from registered URLs.